# How do I translate an LDAP .xml configuration file, to a .java configuration file?

Tags: java, xml, spring, scala, configuration-files

I was tasked with converting an xml configuration file for the Flowable LDAP library, and adding it into the already existing Java configuration for everything else that's being used.

I'm failing to see how the xml, when converted into Java, fits into the already existing Java code. All the examples I've looked at seem to be doing it with Spring LDAP, which is slightly different.

Flowable configuration:

```
<bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="...SomeProcessEngineConfigurationClass">
        ...
        <property name="configurators">
          <list>
              <bean class="org.flowable.ldap.LDAPConfigurator">

                <!-- Server connection params -->
                <property name="server" value="ldap://localhost" />
                <property name="port" value="33389" />
                <property name="user" value="uid=admin, ou=users, o=flowable" />
                <property name="password" value="pass" />

                <!-- Query params -->
                <property name="baseDn" value="o=flowable" />
                <property name="queryUserByUserId" value="(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(uid={0}))" />
                <property name="queryUserByFullNameLike" value="(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(|({0}=*{1}*)({2}=*{3}*)))" />
                <property name="queryGroupsForUser" value="(&(objectClass=groupOfUniqueNames)(uniqueMember={0}))" />

                <!-- Attribute config -->
                <property name="userIdAttribute" value="uid" />
                <property name="userFirstNameAttribute" value="cn" />
                <property name="userLastNameAttribute" value="sn" />
                <property name="userEmailAttribute" value="mail" />


                <property name="groupIdAttribute" value="cn" />
                <property name="groupNameAttribute" value="cn" />

              </bean>
          </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Java Engine configuration file

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = Array("com.name.product.engine.services"))
class FlowableEngineConfig {

  @Bean
  def processEngineConfiguration(env: Environment, dataSource: DataSource, transactionManager: PlatformTransactionManager, applicationContext: ApplicationContext): ProcessEngineConfiguration = {
    val updateSchema = env.getProperty("conduct.engine.database.updateSchema", "true").trim.toLowerCase match {
      case "update" | "true" =>
        AbstractEngineConfiguration.DB_SCHEMA_UPDATE_TRUE
      case "none" =>
        null
      case x =>
        AbstractEngineConfiguration.DB_SCHEMA_UPDATE_FALSE
    }

    val engineConfig = new SpringProcessEngineConfiguration()


    engineConfig.setDataSource(dataSource)
    engineConfig.setTransactionManager(transactionManager)
    engineConfig.setTransactionsExternallyManaged(true)
    engineConfig.setDatabaseSchemaUpdate(updateSchema)

    engineConfig.setAsyncExecutorActivate(true)
    engineConfig.setAsyncExecutor(asyncExecutor())

    engineConfig.setHistoryLevel(HistoryLevel.FULL)


//    engineConfig.setCustomFormTypes(Seq[org.flowable.engine.form.AbstractFormType](
//      ISODateFormType
//    ).asJava)

    engineConfig.setExpressionManager(new SpringExpressionManager(applicationContext, null))
    engineConfig.setBeans(new SpringBeanFactoryProxyMap(applicationContext))

    // Enable safe XML. See http://www.flowable.org/docs/userguide/index.html#advanced.safe.bpmn.xml
    engineConfig.setEnableSafeBpmnXml(true)
    engineConfig.setProcessDefinitionCacheLimit(128)

    //engineConfig.setDisableIdmEngine(true)

    engineConfig.addConfigurator(new SpringFormEngineConfigurator())
    engineConfig.addConfigurator(new SpringDmnEngineConfigurator())

    engineConfig
  }

  @Bean
  def processEngine(engineConfig: ProcessEngineConfiguration): ProcessEngine = {
    engineConfig.buildProcessEngine()
  }

  @Bean
  def clock(engineConfig: ProcessEngineConfiguration): Clock = {
    engineConfig.getClock
  }

  @Bean
  def asyncExecutor(): AsyncExecutor = {
    val asyncExecutor = new DefaultAsyncJobExecutor()
    asyncExecutor.setDefaultAsyncJobAcquireWaitTimeInMillis(5000)
    asyncExecutor.setDefaultTimerJobAcquireWaitTimeInMillis(5000)
    asyncExecutor
  }

  @Bean
  def dataSource(env: Environment): DataSource = {

    val hconf = new HikariConfig()

    env.getRequiredProperty("conductor.engine.database.platform").trim.toLowerCase() match {
      case "postgresql" =>
        hconf.setDataSourceClassName("org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource")
        hconf.addDataSourceProperty("serverName", env.getRequiredProperty("conduct.engine.database.hostname"))
        hconf.addDataSourceProperty("portNumber", env.getRequiredProperty("conduct.engine.database.port", classOf[Int]))
        hconf.addDataSourceProperty("databaseName", env.getRequiredProperty("conduct.engine.database.name"))
        hconf.addDataSourceProperty("applicationName", "conduct")

      case "h2" =>
        hconf.setDataSourceClassName("org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource")
        val dbName = env.getRequiredProperty("conduct.engine.database.name")
        hconf.addDataSourceProperty("URL", s"jdbc:h2:file:./$dbName")

      case "h2mem" =>
        hconf.setDataSourceClassName("org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource")
        val dbName = env.getRequiredProperty("conduct.engine.database.name")
        hconf.addDataSourceProperty("URL", s"jdbc:h2:mem:$dbName")

      case x =>
        throw new RuntimeException(s"Unknown database platform $x")
    }

    hconf.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty("conduct.engine.database.username"))
    hconf.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("conduct.engine.database.password"))

    hconf.setMinimumIdle(env.getRequiredProperty("conduct.engine.database.minConnections", classOf[Int]))
    hconf.setMaximumPoolSize(env.getRequiredProperty("conduct.engine.database.maxConnections", classOf[Int]))

    hconf.setInitializationFailFast(env.getRequiredProperty("conduct.engine.database.initializationFailFast", classOf[Boolean]))

    hconf.setTransactionIsolation("TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED")

    new HikariDataSource(hconf)
  }
```

Comment: @DwB I think I mis stated my question. Im not trying to go from xml to xml, I'm trying to go from xml to Java

Comment: There's no such thing as a "`.java` configuration file"

Comment: You seem to have a Bean, which is represented as a `org.flowable.ldap.LDAPConfigurator` Java class, which is set by a `LDAPConfigurator.java` file, if that is what you mean

Comment: @cricket_007 yes, but I'm having trouble with where within the given code, I'm supposed to integrate the LDAPConfigurator file. I can access the setter and getter methods there to manipulate the server and passwords, etc. I'm just not sure where to place it within the given code.

Comment: I see you have `engineConfig.setBeans`, so there is something that sets the available classes that can be deserialized. I don't know Spring though